# xpages cookies not working in edge

Tags: cookies, xpages-ssjs

I have an xpage which writes a cookie like this:

```
var response = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse(); 
var userCookie = new javax.servlet.http.Cookie("name", "value"); 
userCookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365*10); // set age in seconds...
response.addCookie(userCookie);
```

It seems not working in the edge browser.(but it is in IE and Chrome)

I'm reading back the cookie with :

```
var c = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestCookieMap().get("name");
var example = c.getValue().toString();
```

**EDIT**
It seems to be a local thing on my win 10 computer.

Still I don't know the reason why it doesn't work on my computer so maybe it won't work for others too ...